# js slider website - google crawling

Tags: javascript, slider, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I'm currently building a website with a js slider.
Basically all the pages of the site (slides in this case) are contained in one big html page.

These pages/slides are organized within `<div>` tags, like `<div id="#slide1">, <div id="#slide2" >`, etc

As you slide through the pages/slides, the url is updated, like www.mysite.com/#!slide1, then www.mysite.com/!#slide2, etc

Is it possible to tell the crawling bots that each div should be considered like a page ?

The slides are not loaded in ajax.

Comment: I find it odd that you use the hashbang syntax for the URLs considering mysite.com/#slide1, mysite.com/#slide2 _is_ the way you link to specific sections of a website. Perhaps it's your scrollTo-plugin but I'd consider that a bug.

Answer (score 1):

When you're serving your files with PHP or something like that you can try this:

- create links for all slides which a earch engine could see (e.g. in a site map)
- when a link is called deliver only the requested slide/content as HTML
- store all other slides in JavaScript
- before moving to another slide append the content

Extra advantage:

- even without javascript activated a user could go through all the slides

Disadvantages:

- when your slides contain a lot of content, javascript overhead could get heavy
- it will work best if only one slide is visible at a time (or just append all slides "unload")

Maybe this is a possible idea.

To enhance your URLs you could also use the HTML5 history object, but this won't work in any Internet Explorer before IE10.